# When BACK faces are drawn, are their normals automatically reversed?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I am drawing only back faces of a geometry by invoking `gl.cullFace(gl.FRONT)`. I noticed that the shade of light on these surfaces is opposite to what I expect. For correct rendering, do I have to explicitly reverse the direction of surface normals on back faces, or does the OpenGL subsystem automatically do that?

EDIT: Coming to think of it, if I reverse their normals manually they will become front faces and will be culled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenGL front/back detection is based on winding, not the normal. The normal vector does not have any effect on whether the polygon is considered front or back facing.

I think what you want to do is set the `GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE` option of [glLightModel](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLightModel.xml).

> GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE
>
> params is a single integer or floating-point value that specifies
>                           whether one- or two-sided lighting calculations are done for polygons.
>                           It has no effect on the lighting calculations for points,
>                           lines,
>                           or bitmaps.
>                           If params is 0 (or 0.0), one-sided lighting is specified,
>                           and only the front material parameters are used in the
>                           lighting equation.
>                           Otherwise, two-sided lighting is specified.
>                           In this case, vertices of back-facing polygons are lighted 
>   using  the                         back material parameters
>                           **and have their normals reversed before the lighting equation is evaluated**.
>                           Vertices of front-facing polygons are always lighted using the
>                           front material parameters,
>                           with no change to their normals. The initial value is 0.

Note that this only applies to the fixed pipeline.

===EDIT===

Using custom shaders (GLES2.0 or OpenGL3+), then in the fragment shader you have access to the special boolean `gl_FrontFacing`. To emulate two sided lighting in a shader just test for `gl_FrontFacing` and multiply normal by negative one if `false`.

Comment: Is there an OpenGL-ES equivalent of `glLightModel`?

Comment: OpenGL ES 2.0. WebGL to be specific.

Comment: @Jayesh Edited answer with GLES2.0 instructions.